# Query not being redirected into read replica cluster in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I think I have still misunderstood something about read replicas. It seems that if I run a query that looks like a sequence scan on a read-only replica, the actual read is done on the main cluster. Although the read replica seems to have the whole dataset.

When I ran a simple `select count(*)` query in the  read replica, I expected it to do a local read from its own data.

However, as can be seen from the picture the main nodes actually started to do the reads and the read replica waited in an almost idle state until it got the response from the main node. Where did I go wrong? (using YugabyteDB 2.6)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that read from followers is only available in 2.11 that was recently released: https://blog.yugabyte.com/announcing-yugabytedb-2-11/

Another thing to remember is, even on 2.11, the default behavior, no matter which node you connect to will redirect the read to corresponding leader tablets. You'll have to enable reading from followers in the current session like below:

```
SET yb_read_from_followers = true;
START TRANSACTION READ ONLY;
SELECT * from t WHERE k='k1'; --> follower read
 k  | v
----+----
 k1 | v1
(1 row)
COMMIT;
```

This will let YugabyteDB know that it is ok to read from a follower tablet (that is in a read-replica cluster).

Also, even in the read-replica cluster, the node receiving the request might not have the data. For example, you could have a 5-node read-replica cluster with RF=2 on that cluster. So the node that initially receives the request might not necessarily have the data that the request is interested in. Where the request is routed depends on whether the default setting is being used for the session/statement, which is to read from leader tablets. But if read-from-follower is enabled, then the request will be routed to a follower tablet in the same region.